# &pound; displaying in urllib2 and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to write a small web scraper in python, and I think I've run into an encoding issue. I'm trying to scrape http://www.resident-music.com/tickets (specifically the table on the page) - a row might look something like this -

```
    <tr>
        <td style="width:64.9%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>the great escape 2017&nbsp; local early bird tickets, selling fast</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:13.1%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>18<sup>th</sup>&ndash; 20<sup>th</sup> may</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:15.42%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>various</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:6.58%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>&pound;55.00</strong></p>
        </td>
       </tr>
```

I'm essentially trying to replace the `&pound;55.00` with £55, and any other 'non-text' nasties.

I've tried a few different encoding things you can go with beautifulsoup, and urllib2 - to no avail, I think I'm just doing it all wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *unescape* the html which you can do using *html.unescape* in python3:

```
In [14]: from html import unescape

In [15]: h = """<tr>
   ....:         <td style="width:64.9%;height:11px;">
   ....:          <p><strong>the great escape 2017&nbsp; local early bird tickets, selling fast</strong></p>
   ....:         </td>
   ....:         <td style="width:13.1%;height:11px;">
   ....:          <p><strong>18<sup>th</sup>&ndash; 20<sup>th</sup> may</strong></p>
   ....:         </td>
   ....:         <td style="width:15.42%;height:11px;">
   ....:          <p><strong>various</strong></p>
   ....:         </td>
   ....:         <td style="width:6.58%;height:11px;">
   ....:          <p><strong>&pound;55.00</strong></p>
   ....:         </td>
   ....:        </tr>"""

In [16]: 

In [16]: print(unescape(h))
<tr>
        <td style="width:64.9%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>the great escape 2017  local early bird tickets, selling fast</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:13.1%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>18<sup>th</sup>– 20<sup>th</sup> may</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:15.42%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>various</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:6.58%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>£55.00</strong></p>
        </td>
       </tr>
```

For python2 use:

```
In [6]: from html.parser import HTMLParser

In [7]: unescape = HTMLParser().unescape  

In [8]: print(unescape(h))
<tr>
        <td style="width:64.9%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>the great escape 2017  local early bird tickets, selling fast</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:13.1%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>18<sup>th</sup>– 20<sup>th</sup> may</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:15.42%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>various</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:6.58%;height:11px;">
         <p><strong>£55.00</strong></p>
        </td>
```

You can see both correctly unescape all entities not just the pound sign.

Answer (score 1):

I used `requests` for this but hopefully you can do that using `urllib2` also. So here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('your_url').text)
chart = soup.findAll(name='tr') 
print str(chart).replace('&pound;',unichr(163)) #replace '&pound;' with '£'
```

Now you should take the expected output!

Sample output:

```
...
<strong>£71.50</strong></p>
...
```

Anyway about the parsing you can do it with many ways, what was interesting here is: `print str(chart).replace('&pound;',unichr(163))` which was quite challenging :)

> Update

If you want to escape more than one (or even one) characters (like dashes,pounds etc...), it would be easier/more efficient for you to use a `parser` as in Padraic's answer. Sometimes as you will also read in the comments they handle and other encoding issues.

Comment: This is not how you want to unescape html, this would mean  calling replace for every escaped entity on the page and the initial str itself could also cause an an encoding error. I would also  not encourage the use of BeautifulSoup3.

Comment: I respect your comment but I'll disagree with you, if you take a look at here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml  you will see that those ready made libs do the same as I did in one line of code, with the difference that they give you ready made results which I personally disapprove. In some cases they do the job but this was a very specific and easy task. As for the `bs3` instead of `bs4` , really doesn't matter for what the OP wants to do. But again I respect your opinion!

Comment: *I'm essentially trying to replace the &pound;55.00 with £55, **and any other 'non-text' nasties.***. The *other 'non-text' nasties* are escaped entities which could be any one  of numerous. Also it does matter, bs3 is broken and no longer maintained.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, ok, I guess you are right. I didn't really paid attention to "_and any other 'non-text' nasties_", if he needs to do that for many entities I would use a parser too - as in your example - I will re-edit my answer, and thanks for the feedback/advice  :)